# Java development on Emacs?

Tags: java

Is is exist good package for java development on Emacs?

Good... I mean to support:

```
Debugging 
Code formatting
Code Highlighting 
Help context  
Maven support
Gradle support
and many others things
```

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely check out [lsp-java](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-java#lsp-java) for emacs. It supports all of the above mentioned features but I am not sure about Gradle suppport.
You can install lsp-java via `package.el`.
I am using lsp-java for 6 months now and I would say it is fantastic.